# Where to put interfaces in my project structure

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is my project structure in visual studio. Folders are indicated with a `-` and files with an `*`.

```
Project.Core
- Customer
 - FinancialProcessing
   - RiskAssesors
     * IRiskAssesor
     * HighRiskAssesor
     * LowRiskAssesor
```

Is it better (i.e. common practice, more convenient, less confusing) to put the interface in the `FinancialProcessing` folder than inside the `RiskAssesors` folder?
What do you guys do?

Comment: I put my interfaces in the folder with the implementations. Keeps everything together. However, on occasion (IoC), I put my interfaces in another assembly.

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed. Yes, there might be different opinions. However, each opinion comes with a set of arguments which can help someone to choose the one that fits the need. My opinion: keep them in a different assembly from the implementations. Reasoning: dependency injection, decoupling, maintainability. I could have elaborated more, but the comment section is not the place to do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep the interfaces in the same folder as the class that uses it.